# Who can help me with autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I have problem with jquery autocomplete with database its not working.

My code

test5.php:

```
    <?php
$wynik = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nabk_t_item_tags") 
or die('B&#322;&#261;d zapytania'); 
if(mysql_num_rows($wynik) > 0) { while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($wynik)) { 
$input = $r['tags'] ;
    $fields = explode(',', $input);
    foreach($fields as $field) {
        echo ''.$field.'<br>'; }}} 
?>
```

and javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = <?php include('test5.php'); ?>;
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            autoFocus:true
        });
    });
    </script>
```

please help me what i doing wrong?

Comment: Include inlines a php file but doesn't return data. You'll need to include the file first and then assign the contents ot $wynik to availableTags. Currently you are trying to assign the file.

Comment: The problem is that you're not outputting whatever comes from `test5.php` as something jQuery sees as an array. Just have your results from the database put in a single array, then use `json_encode()` on it.

Comment: I see mysql_* . I run.

Comment: how to do it? I have no idea, I tried "echo json_encode($field);" but does not work also...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<?php
     $wynik = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nabk_t_item_tags") 
         or die('B&#322;&#261;d zapytania'); 
     if(mysql_num_rows($wynik) > 0) { while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($wynik)) { 
       $input = $r['tags'] ;
       $fields = explode(',', $input);
       foreach($fields as $field) {
    echo '"'.$field.'",'; }}} 

?>

 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [<?php include('test5.php'); ?>];
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        autoFocus:true
    });
});
</script>
```